# Un mot pour un anniversaire chaque mois au lieu de chaque année

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, noms

Existe-t-il une version mensuelle du mot "anniversaire"?

"anniversaire" est formé des mots latins "annus" (année) et "versus" (revenir).
Comme le mot "mois" vient de "mensis", je me demande s'il existe un mot du genre "mensiversaire"?

Un tel mot ne semble pas apparaître dans mon petit Robert.

Contexte: Mon fils a trois mois depuis quelque jours. Je me suis donc demandé comment lui souhaiter un "joyeux troisième (..)". Où (..) est le mot que je cherche.

Comment: « Joyeux troisième *mois* » ?

Comment: @Toto :) l'idée est bonne, mais c'est pas très courant de dire "joyeuse troisième année", non?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensiversaire

Comment: @Jylo Je dois avouer que je ne m'y attendais pas. Ok, donc j'ai deviné juste au final. Je suis néanmoins surpris que ce mot n'apparaisse pas dans mon petit Robert (qui n'est pas si petit que ça).

Comment: Remarquez aussi que "mois-niversaire" est parfois utilisé, surtout à l'oral (mais ça n'en fait pas un vrai mot).

Comment: @Rightleg jamais entendu mais prête sympathiquement au jeux de mots. On pourrait aussi imaginer un "toit-niversaire" pour que chacun ait son *soie-niversaire".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mensiversaire est peu utilisé mais existe réellement, d'après [wiktionnary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensiversaire):

> (Rare) Retour mensuel d’un jour marqué par un événement.

Comment: Attention car j'ai remarqué que Wiktionnaire incluait énormément de mots qui n'apparaissent pas ailleurs, des termes modernes, des termes anglais utilisés en français, des néologismes cohérents (comme ici), même des mauvaises orthographes de certains mots, en gros tout ce qui ressort régulièrement. Je veux dire par là que Wiktionnaire est utile à titre informatif mais ne fait pas foi pour savoir si un mot est "officiel". D'ailleurs le seul autre dico en ligne qui mentionne *mensiversaire* est http://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/mensiversaire.html , "le dictionnaire pas académique".

Answer (score 2):

Il faut simplement avoir le courage d'inaugurer
soi-même un néologisme. C'est en effet surtout dans
le contexte d'un bébé qu'on a envie de lui souhaiter
chaque mois un bon mensuaire !

Comment: Bienvenue Aaron.  Normalement les néologismes ne répondent pas à la question.  Il y a une source par hasard ?  Voici le centre [help] et le [tour] de French Language SE.